# Issue with Internet connection on fresh Arch install

Tags: arch-linux, dhcp, internet, dhcpcd

I am trying to connect to the Internet via Ethernet on a freshly installed Arch Linux system. I am following [this YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NchV5UphQeQ).

Once I got to the Internet part, I started having issues. I cannot enable `dhcpcd` with `systemctl enable dhcpcd@ens18`. I get an error saying

```
dhcpcd service does not exist
```

I tried checking the ArchWiki and using that as a solution. 
I looked at [the Network configuration/Ethernet page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_configuration/Ethernet#Device_driver)
and tried the following things:

Run `lspci -v | less` and look for Ethernet adapter. 
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kQST.jpg) is a photograph of that section
(sorry for the bad quality).

Then, I ran `dmesg | grep e1000e`. 
I got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Y3LM.jpg); I'm not sure if this is good or bad.

I don't know how to proceed from here. I think that the issue is that `dhcpcd` is not installed, but with no Internet, I don't know how to install it. 
I still have the live USB, so maybe try and remount everything
and run `pacman -S dhcpcd`?

Comment: I think Arch ships with `dhclient` so you can use that instead of `dhcpcd` for getting ip

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. Could you please elaborate further? Do you mean using `systemctl enable dhclient`?

Comment: Simply run `dhclient <interface>` for example `dhclient ens2`. You can list interfaces with `ip link` and `ip addr`.

Comment: Please post command output as text, not as images. And, if you do have images to post, upload them through the Stack Exchange / imgur interface.